# Remove $ symbol in Android EditText

Tags: android

I'm using this code to have a currency format on Android EditText control.
But how can I remove the $ symbol (or replace with another symbol) from the result?

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    if (!s.toString().equals(current)) {
        inputValue.removeTextChangedListener(this);

        String cleanString = s.toString().replaceAll("\\D", "");

        if (cleanString.length() > 0) {
            double parsed = Double.parseDouble(cleanString);
            NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
            formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
            current = formatter.format(parsed);
        } else {
            current = cleanString;
        }


        inputValue.setText(current);
        inputValue.setSelection(current.length());
        inputValue.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jxm3j.png)

Comment: string.replace("$","*");

Comment: @Vu Duong Can you put your whole `addTextChangedListener` Code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heyy Vu Duong, I've tried something like this. Hope this helps you

```
  @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        if (!s.toString().equals(current)) {
            inputValue.removeTextChangedListener(this);

            String cleanString = s.toString().replaceAll("\\D", "");

            if (cleanString.length() > 0) {
                double parsed = Double.parseDouble(cleanString);
                NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
                formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
                current = formatter.format(parsed);
                sub = current.substring(1, current.length());

            } else {
                current = cleanString;
            }

            inputValue.setText(current);
            inputValue.setSelection(current.length());
            inputValue.addTextChangedListener(this);
            Log.e("Amount ", "::" + sub);
        }
    }
```

What I've done here is, just added a `String sub`, which holds the value that you've entered in EditText. But note that `String stub` only takes value from position 1 (i.e. excluding $). If you go through the code i've printed it in log. So you can use this sub value further.

Comment: If your problem is solved then just click on the (✓check) mark.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works!
I'd to add a note here:

inputValue.setText(sub);
inputValue.setSelection(sub.length());

==> To set sub to the TextView, I need to change the setSelection to sub.length(). Otherwise, the app will Force closed.